# Limit width with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I position the `:before` and `:after` content to the edge of the `.container` using flexbox?

I am trying to position the `<` to the left and `>` to the right but these elements should align according to the `.container` width.

I tried:

```
text-align: left;
max-width: 50%;
```

but doesn't work. What am I missing here?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 8px 0;
}
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.prev {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
.prev::before {
  content: '<';
}
.next::after {
  content: '>';
}
.link {
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
.link:first-child {
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  max-width: 50%;
}
.link:last-child {
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi earum pariatur, sint, fugiat veniam porro deserunt laboriosam odio obcaecati, repellat numquam placeat aliquid nobis dolor temporibus. Soluta ipsam, quod consectetur tenetur quibusdam
    aut assumenda accusamus ex perferendis ipsa aperiam sapiente.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flexbox">
  <a href="#" class="link prev">Preview</a>
  <a href="#" class="link next">Next</a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/4sq3gufn/1/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. **An image of what this is supposed to look like would help**. Plus your flexbox isn't even in the container!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, put the `.flexbox` inside the `.container`:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi earum pariatur, sint, fugiat veniam porro deserunt laboriosam odio obcaecati, repellat numquam placeat aliquid nobis dolor temporibus. Soluta ipsam, quod consectetur tenetur quibusdam aut assumenda accusamus ex perferendis ipsa aperiam sapiente.
    <div class="flexbox">
      <a href="#" class="link prev">Preview</a>
      <a href="#" class="link next">Next</a>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Then set `position:absolute` for `::before` and `::after`.

```
.prev {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  &::before {
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    content: '<';
  }
}

.next {
  &::after {
    position:absolute;
    right:20px;
    content: '>';
  }
}
```

Set `position:relative` to `.container` so the `<` and `>` will be kept within its borders:

```
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 8px 0 0 0;
  position:relative;
}
```

Set width of `.flexbox` to be `100vw` (viewport width), and add some magic of `calc` to calculate the negative `margin-left` to keep the `.flexbox` in the middle:

```
   .flexbox {
      display: flex;
      background: blue;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width:100vw;
      margin-left: calc((-100vw + 100%)/2);
    }
```

[Working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/6ytrmvgo/4/)

Comment: Yes I know that, but how can I limit the `<` and `>` to the width of the .container ?

Comment: I've edited my answer, hope it is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

not too sure if  the idea is to have links **beneath** the box.

If so then use also `max-width` on the flex container and update `justify-content`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.prev::before {
  content: '<';
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.next::after {
  content: '>';
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.link {
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi earum pariatur, sint, fugiat veniam porro deserunt laboriosam odio obcaecati, repellat numquam placeat aliquid nobis dolor temporibus. Soluta ipsam, quod consectetur tenetur quibusdam aut assumenda accusamus ex perferendis ipsa aperiam sapiente.
  </div>
</div>


<div class="flexbox">
  <a href="#" class="link prev">Preview</a>
  <a href="#" class="link next">Next</a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4sq3gufn/6/

or maybe this ? https://jsfiddle.net/4sq3gufn/7/ for the links to cover half of the width.

Answer (score -1):

You can just float 'em, given that you make some small adjustements to your code (`width: 50%` instead of `flex: 0 0 50%`).

https://jsfiddle.net/4sq3gufn/3/

```
.link {
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 50%;
}

.prev {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  text-align: right;
  &::before {
    content: '<';
    float: left;
  }
}

.next {
  text-align: left;
  &::after {
    content: '>';
    float: right;
  }
}
```